# How to download windows 10 development tools

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

My English in not good so do not laugh at me !! :)

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2015 but Windows 10 universal app tools (include Windows 10 mobile emulator etc ) did not install with it!!

Can I download this tools as an ISO or exe file?

It seems we can download and add this tools just through Visual Studio installer?

But I want an ISO file, so I can download it with my IDM and reinstall it for my friends or my other PC's.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: from what i know universal tools only ship with the enterprise version

Comment: It is possible to download the standalone SDK. https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: In VS2015 - Go to the Tools menu - Extensions and Updates - Tools section

Answer (score 4):

> i have installed visual studio community 2015 but windows 10 universal app tools(include windows 10 mobile emulator and etc ) did not install with it !!

There is a point in the installation where you can set which features you want to install together with Visual Studio. Make sure you have checked **Universal Windows App Development Tools**.

[image: Feature selection]

When the installation is completed, start your Visual Studio and you should be able to create UWP project by selecting **Blank App (Universal Windows)** in **New Project** dialog.

[image: New Project dialog]

> can i download this tools as an ISO or exe file ?

There is both ISO and Web [installer of Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-community). As far as I know the Universal App Development tools are not part of the ISO installer and they are downloaded during the installation.

**UPDATE:**
[Windows Standalone SDK for Windows 10](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) allows you to download offline installer for installation on other computers.

Comment: ok thank you but i know Universal App Development tools are not part of the ISO installer and they are downloaded during the installation. why we can't download them and reuse them later in separate PC or next Windows fresh installs  !!!

Comment: To download a tailored installer for offline installations, you can use the /layout switch and define the packages you need. More information about offline installs can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx. Scroll down to "Downloading Visual Studio for an offline installation"

Answer (score 3):

Both on 7GB offline ISO of Community and Enterprise version of VS, there is no packages of Windows 10 SDK and UWP tools, it will download and install it via online. For Windows 10 SDK, you can download 1MB sdksetup.exe from https://developer.microsoft.com/downloads/windows-10-sdk and choose to download on the program.
There is /layout command that can be used with VS setup(like vs_community.exe) of mounted iso, see details here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx), I have not tried it yet.

As of yet I have not found standalone ISO file for Windows 10 SDK+UWP tools that can be fully offline installed. You can vote here, https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13453152-offline-windows-10-sdk-and-uwp-tools

Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/03340f34-4674-47e7-90f0-65076701e847/vs2015-uwp-template-prompting-to-install-universal-windows-tools?forum=vssetup

Comment: OK thank you !! "As of yet I have not found standalone ISO file for Windows 10 SDK+UWP tools that can be fully offline installed. You can vote here" i will :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding additional information to @amit-sharma answer

**UWP Tools and Windows 10 SDK Offline**

First Download Windows 10 SDK from: -

[Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Windows 10 SDK offline installer that will download 700 MB of files and we can use those files to install Windows 10 SDK to another PC.

After installing Windows 10 SDK we need to install UWP tools for Windows 10. From this link we will get UWP Tools offline: -

**UWP tools installer**
Locate the windows_vstools.exe file here

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\Win10_VSTools_14.0.25527\en\0
```

(The version number may be different for your installation)

Copy and save **windows_vstools.exe** to some temporary folder.
Go to the directory where you save UWP Tools installer i.e. **windows_vstools.exe**.
Now **Shift Key + Right Click** and select **open command window here**
CMD will open.

And type: -
**windows_vstools.exe /Layout** and press **Enter**.

[image: Command Prompt]

After that Installer will ask you for Download Location i.e. Where to save UWP Tools files.

Then **Select Download Location** and **Click Download**.

[image: Download Preparation Screenshot]

If download fails, it will ask for retry as shown below

[image: Download setup to offline]

After downloading is finished you can install UWP tools on multiple PCs.

Answer (score -1):

**Want UWP Tools and Windows 10 SDK Offline**

First Download Windows 10 SDK from: -

[Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Windows 10 SDK offline installer that will download 700 MB of files and we can use those files to intall Windows 10 SDK to another PC.

After installing Windows 10 SDK we need to install UWP tools for Windows 10.
From this link we will get UWP Tools offline: -

[UWP tools installer](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AppnmrbvPRejhR4NdD1_oc703X-s)

After downloading you find **windows_vstools.exe**.
Go to the directory where you save UWP Tools installer i.e. **windows_vstools.exe**.

Now **Shift Key + Right Click** and select **open command window here**

CMD will open.

And type: -

**windows_vstools.exe /Layout** and press Enter.

After that Installer will ask you for Download Location i.e. Where to save UWP Tools files.

Then Click Download.

After Downloading finish you can install UWP tools on multiple PCs.

Enjoy

**Amit Sharma**

amit8sharma@hotmail.com